# Cannot get a value in a object from out of a another object (java processing)

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

It works in processing, but it does not work in Eclipse, why?
I want an object getting a value from another object, it seemed simple enough, but for some reason I get "test cannot be resolved".
Help appreciated, sorry if I am unclear or if my question is too beginner, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

```
package testclasinterchanceval;

import processing.core.PApplet;



    public class Testclasinterchanceval extends PApplet {

        public void setup() {


        }

        public void draw() {

             Test test = new Test (20);
             Apples apples = new Apples (50);

            strokeWeight(7);
            point (70,50);

            println( apples.accesTest() );
        }
    }

    package testclasinterchanceval;

    public class Test {

        public float i;
        Test( float _i ){ i = _i; }


        float getVal() {

        return this.i;
        }

    }

    package testclasinterchanceval;

    public class Apples {

        public float i;

        Apples( float _i ){ i = _i; }


        float accesTest(){
        float t = test.getVal();
        return t ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you have all these code in a single file?

Comment: No, its in 3 parts, but shown here together I changed float "t = test.getVal(); "into "float t = ((Test) test).getVal();" which does get the error away, but its still not working properly...

Comment: Which class/ line you are getting this error?

Comment: all classes are in different file???

Comment: Could you show your main method code and OP as well?

Comment: the main method is the first class, sorrt, whats an OP? (noob here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting the issue in ...

```
public class Apples {

    public float i;

    Apples( float _i ){ i = _i; }


    float accesTest(){
    float t = test.getVal();
    return t ;
    }
}
```

You have not defined the variable `test` here. You can add this as an instance variable and initialize it over there, pass through constructor based on your design.

What you should do is...

```
public void draw() {

         Test test = new Test (20);
         Apples apples = new Apples (50);

        strokeWeight(7);
        point (70,50);

        println( apples.accesTest(test ) );
    }
```

And change the method signature of `accessTest()` to have `Test test` as a method parameter and use.

```
public class Apples {

    public float i;

    Apples( float _i ){ i = _i; }


    float accesTest(Test test){
    float t = test.getVal();
    return t ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer for your better understanding. Don't get confused and use some type casting from Test to float. It will give you compilation error.

Comment: I changed it into ;    Test test = new Test (20);
    float t = ((Test) test).getVal();, no compiling error, and the result is 20, which is correct.

Comment: Are you not getting a compilation error? Only use float t = test.getVal(). Anyway, please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: No, no compilation error, wierd, anyway, I better take your solution, I don't trust mine :)